# Google Chart ChartWrapper's draw() does not work in Async

Tags: angular, typescript, google-visualization

I am struggling with screen freezing issue of a bars chart.
I have 5.6 M data to render and I put on my Options like below,

```js
let options = {
    seriesType: "bars",
    fontSize: 10,
    lineWidth: 3,
    allowAsync: true,
    animation: {
        startup: true
    },
    bar: {
        groupWidth: "100%"
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: "",
        baselineColor: "white",
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 90,
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0
        }
    }
};
```

And then I call, the `draw()` method would lock whole screen for 6-7 seconds while I could not do anything but freeze there.

```js
this.wrapper.setOptions(options);
this.wrapper.draw();
```

`this.wrapper` is the object of `google.visualization.ChartWrapper`.  Does anyone know how to cope with this?